# how to convert this date format to our regular date in objective-c

Tags: ios, objective-c, date, nsdateformatter

I have a date in the following format

```
11/03/2562 BE, 21:45:57
14/03/2562 BE, 10:42:05
14/03/2562 BE, 21:12:14
```

I want to convert those dates in current regular date format. 
What should be the value of `NSDateFormatter` in objective-c for above date string?

Comment: I think its `NSCalendarIdentifierBuddhist` calendar in iPhone

Answer (score 2):

You have to create two formatters - one for converting buddhist date string to NSDate and one for converting NSDate to gregorian date string

`'` - used to escape symbols within date format string

```
    NSString *buddhistString = @"11/03/2562 BE, 21:45:57";

    NSDateFormatter *buddhistFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    buddhistFormatter.dateFormat = @"dd/MM/yyyy GG, HH:mm:ss";
    buddhistFormatter.calendar = [NSCalendar calendarWithIdentifier:NSCalendarIdentifierBuddhist];

    NSDateFormatter *gregorianFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    gregorianFormatter.dateFormat = @"dd/MM/yyyy, HH:mm:ss"; // Or other format you'd like
    gregorianFormatter.calendar = [NSCalendar calendarWithIdentifier:NSCalendarIdentifierGregorian];

    NSDate *date = [buddhistFormatter dateFromString:buddhistString];
    NSString *gregorianString = [gregorianFormatter stringFromDate:date];

    NSLog(@"%@", gregorianString);
    // prints 11/03/2019, 21:45:57
```

Comment: Do not escape the era. Replace your use of `'BE'` with `GG` (without the apostrophes).